# Dynamic column width size in crosstab

Tags: jasper-reports, pivot-table

I'm developing software where I get a dynamic list of columns with a column title and a set of values.

To generate a report from this table, I'm using the Jasper Reports library in version 6.19.1 using crosstab. The problem is that in the crosstab I didn't find a way for the columns to change width dynamically. All of them have the same fixed size of 60px and when the title of a column or its values are big I would like to change the size to be more pleasant for the user.

Is there any way to do this?

I tried to calculate the width in Java and send an object already containing this dynamic width value as field. So I transformed it to a variable and tried to put it in the width, but it doesn't consider this operation valid. I imagine it only accepts constant width values. What I got was this:

`net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 220; columnNumber: 57; cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '$V{cellWidth}' is not a valid value for 'NMTOKEN'.`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem using Java with extra class, before to compile report.jrxml to report.jasper.
In my case, I needed my report to dynamically adjust and expand in width to occupy the entire space available.
However, this only applies when the width of the columns didn't exceed the total width of the report.
To solve this issue:

*Create the report with JasperSoft Design, including the crosstab,
and assign the appropriate keys to these elements that you want to make dynamic.

*Create a custom class implementation for allow set dynamic width

*Set width Cell and TextFields inside the crosstab.
The calculated width is based on the n-columns in the crosstab divided by the available size of the report.
(n-columns/available width) = dynamic width

It's not a perfect solution, but it works for me!

**Custom class implementation**

```
public class JRDesignCellContentsCustom extends JRDesignCellContents implements JRCellContents {
    public JRDesignCellContentsCustom() {
        super();
    }

    public JRDesignCellContentsCustom(JRDesignCellContents jrDesignCellContents, List<JRDesignElement> listaJRDesignElement) {
        super();

        //Copy values...
        setWidth(jrDesignCellContents.getWidth()); //<- Now you can access the protected method and set the width wathever you want
        setBackcolor(jrDesignCellContents.getBackcolor());
        setHeight(jrDesignCellContents.getHeight());
        setStyle(jrDesignCellContents.getStyle());
        setMode(jrDesignCellContents.getModeValue());
        setStyleNameReference(jrDesignCellContents.getStyleNameReference());
        setOrigin(jrDesignCellContents.getOrigin());
        setElementGroup(jrDesignCellContents.getElementGroup());

        /*
         * This is to add the child elements that are inside your cell, which you obtained using keys.
         * JRDesignTextField, JRDesignStaticText... etc
         * */
        listaJRDesignElement.forEach(this::addElement);
    }

    // You need to override setWidth to change protected to public and set the width from the custom class
    // Wherever you want
    @Override
    public void setWidth(int width) {
        super.setWidth(width);
    }
}
```

Then compile and export code:

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream reportWithDynamicColumnSizeByParameter(Map<String, Object> params, Connection con) throws IOException, JRException {
        params.put("nColumns", 4);

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        String srcFileName = "detalle_calificacion";
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource(REPORT_FOLDER + File.separator + srcFileName + JRXML);
        InputStream reportStream = resource.getInputStream();

        try {
            JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(reportStream);
            //You need to set the element key on JasperSoft Design to find the crosstab.
            //In this case, I set crosstab in the first detail band with the element key "crosstab".
            JRElement jrElement = jasperDesign.getDetailSection().getBands()[0].getElementByKey("crosstab");

            //Then verify if it's a crosstab
            if (jrElement instanceof JRDesignCrosstab jrDesignCrosstab) {
                /*===Dynamic Column Group===*/
                JRDesignCrosstabColumnGroup columnGroupActividad = (JRDesignCrosstabColumnGroup) jrDesignCrosstab.getColumnGroups()[0];
                int nColumns = (int) params.get("nColumns");
                params.remove("nColumns"); //Not pass params to report


                final int availableWidth = 442; //<-- This is the width of my report, you can change whatever you want
                //as long as it doesn't exceed the width of your report

                // + 1 is for total column group
                final int dynamicCellWidth = availableWidth / (nColumns + 1);

                /*
                 * ====================== SECTION COLUMN GROUP HEADER =============================
                 * */
                System.out.println("=== COLUMN GROUP : " + columnGroupActividad.getName() + " ===");
                JRDesignCellContents header = (JRDesignCellContents) columnGroupActividad.getHeader();

                JRDesignTextField activityName = (JRDesignTextField) header.getElementByKey("nombre_actividad");
                JRDesignTextField percentage = (JRDesignTextField) header.getElementByKey("porcentaje");
                activityName.setWidth(dynamicCellWidth);
                percentage.setWidth(dynamicCellWidth);
                System.out.println("=== EXPECTED CHANGES ===");
                System.out.println("ACTIVITY NAME(width: " + activityName.getWidth() + ", height: " + activityName.getHeight() + ")");
                System.out.println("PERCENTAGE(width: " + percentage.getWidth() + ", height: " + percentage.getHeight() + ")");

                /*
                 * Unfortunately, you cannot set the width of the crosstab cells directly because it is a protected method,
                 * and you need to inherit a CustomClass from JRDesignCellContents to access those methods.
                 *
                 * @see JRDesignCellContentsCustom for more information.
                 * */
                JRDesignCellContentsCustom customHeader = new JRDesignCellContentsCustom((JRDesignCellContents) header.clone(), List.of(activityName, percentage));

                //It is assigned to the ColumnGroup with the new width to work (This must be the same as the JDesignTextField.getWidth())
                customHeader.setWidth(dynamicCellWidth);
                //Set to the column group the custom header to the crosstab
                columnGroupActividad.setHeader(customHeader);

                //We obtain the cells of the crosstab, in position 0. There will always be the Measure Cell
                List<JRCrosstabCell> measureCells = ((JRDesignCrosstab) jrElement).getCellsList();
                ((JRDesignCrosstabCell) measureCells.get(0)).setWidth(dynamicCellWidth);

                //and the same for the TextField inside the measure cells
                JRDesignTextField score = (JRDesignTextField) jrDesignCrosstab.getElementByKey("calificacion");
                score.setWidth(dynamicCellWidth);

                System.out.println("=== EXPECTED CHANGES ===");
                System.out.println("SCORE(width: " + score.getWidth() + ", height: " + score.getHeight() + ")");


                /*
                 * ====================== SECTION COLUMN GROUP TOTAL =============================
                 * */
                JRDesignCellContents totalHeader = (JRDesignCellContents) columnGroupActividad.getTotalHeader();
                System.out.println("=== COLUMN GROUP TOTAL: " + columnGroupActividad.getName() + " ===");

                //Repeat the process...
                JRDesignStaticText labelFinalScore = (JRDesignStaticText) totalHeader.getElementByKey("label_nota_final");
                labelFinalScore.setWidth(dynamicCellWidth);

                JRDesignCellContentsCustom customTotalHeader = new JRDesignCellContentsCustom((JRDesignCellContents) totalHeader.clone(), List.of(labelFinalScore));
                customTotalHeader.setWidth(dynamicCellWidth);
                columnGroupActividad.setTotalHeader(customTotalHeader);


                //the measure cell in position 1 is total...
                ((JRDesignCrosstabCell) measureCells.get(1)).setWidth(availableWidth);
                JRDesignTextField finalScore = (JRDesignTextField) jrDesignCrosstab.getElementByKey("calificacion_final");
                finalScore.setWidth(dynamicCellWidth);
            }

            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, con);
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, stream);
        } finally {
            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return stream;
    }
```